# TFS 2010 server responds to remote connections from iPhone but not Windows clients

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, team-foundation-server

I've set up TFS on my home computer so that I can sync my projects back and forth between home, school and work. I installed it on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate using the advanced configuration so that I could set the port to something not blocked by my ISP.

The problem I'm having is that I can't connect to my home computer from school or work. It won't even respond to ping, much less allow me to even connect to TFS or VPN. Normally I'd just assume I've messed something up or that my ISP is still blocking that port, but my iPhone is able to connect to the TFS web interface just fine over AT&Ts data network.

What have I done so horribly wrong that my TFS server only responds to my iPhone and not my freakin' laptop?

Thanks!
-Eric

EDIT: I should point out that my laptop can connect just fine when it's connected to my home WAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because TFS needs to use a proxy server to talk to your home machine, or that your proxy server is blocking access to port 8080?

Can you access your home machine from your web browser?

Comment: I can't access my home machine from my web browser, no. It won't respond to ping, but Windows Live Mesh remote desktop works. Also, I set TFS to use a port other than 8080 since my ISP blocks that outgoing port.

Comment: Ultimately the issue turned out to be my college network blocks seemingly random ports. Want to connect to my TFS install at home on port 1337? Nope. Want to test out some of the Xbox Live features I put into my game during my break? Not a chance, buddy! Thankfully since then I've just gotten a VPS server and TFS works perfectly.